# Confirm or Cancel MessageDialog

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I'm trying to make a function that shows a dialog where the user should select to confirm the deletion of an entry on a table or to cancel it.

I've searched about that topic and thats what I've reached in terms of code:

```
public static bool ConfirmDelete(string table, string rowid)
{


   var result = PopupMessageHelper.ShowWithOptionsAsync($"Tem a certeza que pretende eliminar a linha correspondente ao identificador {rowid} da tabela {table}").Result;

        if (!result)
        {
            return false;
        } else if (result)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


 public static async Task<bool> ShowWithOptionsAsync(string text)
        {
            var yesCommand = new UICommand(LocalizationHelper.GetValue("txt_keyword_submit"));
            var noCommand = new UICommand(LocalizationHelper.GetValue("txt_keyword_cancel"));

            var messageDialog = new MessageDialog(text);
            messageDialog.Options = MessageDialogOptions.None;
            messageDialog.Commands.Add(yesCommand);
            messageDialog.Commands.Add(noCommand);
          
            var command = await messageDialog.ShowAsync();

            if (command == yesCommand)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (command == noCommand)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }  
        }
    }
```

Visual studio isn't returning any error but when I execute that part of code it deadlocks.
Any hint on I can get this working? :)

Comment: Never use `Task.Result`, use await within an async method instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ConfirmDelete` method should return a `Task<bool>`:

```
public static async Task<bool> ConfirmDelete(string table, string rowid)
{
    var result = await PopupMessageHelper
        .ShowWithOptionsAsync($"Tem a certeza que pretende eliminar a linha correspondente ao identificador {rowid} da tabela {table}");

    if (!result)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (result)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

...and be awaited in the method where you call it:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await ConfirmDelete("...", "...");
}
```

You should not block by using the `.Result` property.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using async method, probably you'll need some kind of await there

Like:

```
public static async Task<bool> ConfirmDeleteAsync(string table, string rowid)
{
    return await PopupMessageHelper.ShowWithOptionsAsync($"Tem a certeza que pretende eliminar a linha correspondente ao identificador {rowid} da tabela {table}");
}
```

Comment: There is any await method on that function

Comment: Using that when I call the  `ConfirmDelete()`  inside an if it says that I cannot convert Task<bool> to bool